# Android Bluetooth cannot be turn on, after it has been turned off while BluetoothServerSocket.accept() is working

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an Android program that uses Bluetooth.
The first device is Haier W718 Android 4.0.3 , the second one is Samsung GT-P5110 Android 4.2.2. They both listen and may connect each other and transmit some data.

Almost everything works properly but I encountered a strange problem in Haier W718. 
If I turn off Bluetooth of my Haier device, when my program is listening (BluetoothServerSocket.accept()), sometimes I can not turn on Bluetooth again. I press the Bluetooth icon in the status bar, but nothing happens.
In case I manage to turn Bluetooth on, BluetoothSocket.connect() gives me the error "IOException Service discovery failed", however BluetoothServerSocket.accept() works good.
In order to solve this problem I have to turn my phone off and on again.

What may be the reason of this strange behavior? 
I have only 2 Android devices and Samsung works good. May it be a problem of Haier firmware?